# How to convert Int64Index to Index ( read from a CSV)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file, contents are:

[image]

Then I read this file by:

```
A = pd.read_csv("MyTest2.csv")
A.columns
```

Output is

```
Index(['ID', '202005'], dtype='object')
```

But if I transport the dataframe and remove some unused column, by:

```
A = pd.read_csv("MyTest2.csv")
A = A.T
A = A.rename(columns=A.iloc[0])
A = A.drop(A.index[0])
A.columns
```

The output will become:

```
Int64Index([1234, 1235, 1236, 1237, 1238, 1239, 1240, 1241, 1242, 1243], dtype='int64')
```

My question is I want to use A["1234"] to read column value, not A[1234](without double quotes).

How to convert Int64Index to Index? Or maybe a correct method to prevent index become Int64Index(or RangeIndex) during transport calculation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Convert the `ID` column to a `str` type with `.astype`

```py
A = pd.read_csv("MyTest2.csv")  # create the dataframe

A.ID = A.ID.astype('str')  # convert ID to a str type
```

- Set the `dtype` when you read in the file

```py
A = pd.read_csv('MyTest2.csv', dtype={'ID': str})
```